# growing view and MotionEvent.getX()/MotionEvent.getRawX()

Tags: android, math, touch, motionevent

I have the following code to be able to expand a tile. However I have more than one of these tiles and I need the code to be universal to each and everyone of them.

UI when booted: http://s14.postimage.org/9wn8b2my9/Screenshot_2012_09_14_12_03_14.png

I have two options to work with:

Number one is to use the raw X,Y values, meaning the exact position of my finger on the screen. This way I can rather easily calculate the accurate width, height and distance to several points. One problem is that this value doesn't work for all the tiles. For example, the tile on the upper left will not expand and the tile in the bottom left will expand to a level way beyond what it should. The only tile that actually seems to listen is the one in the middle.

```
else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {         
        if((newPos.x > this.leftParent.getX()) && (newPos.x < this.rightParent.getX())){
            //reposition the touch indicator
            this.child.setX(newPos.x-42); //-42 because pic = 84dp
            this.child.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        if((newPos.y < this.bottomParent.getY()) && (newPos.y > this.topParent.getY())){
            this.child.setY(newPos.y-42);
            this.child.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        if((this.rightParent.getX() - newPos.x) < this.originalSize.x){
            // X too narrow
            this.leftParent.setX((float) (this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x));
            Log.e("loc", "X TOO NARROW");
        } else if((this.rightParent.getX() - newPos.x) > this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x*1.6){
            // X too wide
            Log.e("loc", "X TOO WIDE newPos: "+newPos.x+", "+newPos.y+" new width:"+(this.rightParent.getX() - newPos.x)+ " old width:"+(this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x*1.6));
        } else if(((this.rightParent.getX() - newPos.x) > this.originalSize.x) && ((this.rightParent.getX() - newPos.x) < this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x*1.6)){ 
            // X inbetween required values
            elasticPosition.x = (int) Math.pow(Math.E, -newPos.x);
            this.leftParent.setX(newPos.x);
            Log.e("loc", "X OK");
        }

        if((this.bottomParent.getY() - newPos.y) < this.originalSize.y){
            // Y too narrow
            this.topParent.setY(this.bottomParent.getY()-this.originalSize.y);
            Log.e("loc", "Y TOO NARROW");
        } else if((this.bottomParent.getY() - newPos.y) > this.bottomParent.getY()-this.originalSize.y*1.6){
            // Y too wide
            Log.e("loc", "Y TOO WIDE");
        } else if(((this.bottomParent.getY() - newPos.y) > this.originalSize.y) && ((this.bottomParent.getY() - newPos.y) < this.bottomParent.getY()-this.originalSize.y*1.6)){
            // Y inbetween required values
            //elasticPosition.y = (int) Math.pow(Math.E, -newPos.y);        //shaving this for a rainy day
            this.topParent.setY(newPos.y);

            Log.e("loc", "Y OK");
        }
```

Tile refusing to stretch: http://s12.postimage.org/ltunmbt7x/Screenshot_2012_09_14_12_03_31.png (logs that the tile is already beyond it's maximum boundaries)

Number two is using the X,Y values in comparison to the parent object's location. This one produces easier formulas and currently holds my preference. However, since the tiles happen to expand, the value does too. In the top left corner of a tile the values are (0,0), if I cross that corner the value will drop to a negative value. However if I contract the tile again I will get a positive value all of a sudden and it will make everything shaky and buggy and glitchy and what more.

```
if(event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < this.getX() + this.getAccurateSize().x){
            //inbetween original values
            this.leftParent.setX((float) (this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x));
            Log.e("touch x", "inbetween original values");
        } else if(event.getX() < (0 - originalSize.x*0.6)){
            //too wide
            this.leftParent.setX((float) (this.rightParent.getX()-this.originalSize.x*1.6));
            Log.e("touch x", "too wide");
        } else if(event.getX() < 0 && event.getX() > (0 - originalSize.x*0.6)){
            //inbetween stretched values
            this.leftParent.setX(newPos.x);
            Log.e("touch x", "inbetween stretched values");
        }

        if(event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < this.getY() + this.getAccurateSize().y){
            //inbetween original values
            this.topParent.setY(this.bottomParent.getY()-this.originalSize.y);
            Log.e("touch y", "inbetween original values");
        } else if(event.getY() < (0 - originalSize.y*0.6)){
            //too wide
            this.topParent.setY((float) (this.bottomParent.getY()-(this.originalSize.y*1.6)));
            Log.e("touch y", "too wide");
        } else if(event.getY() < 0 && event.getY() > (0 - originalSize.y*0.6)){
            //inbetween stretched values
            this.topParent.setY(newPos.y);
            Log.e("touch y", "inbetween stretched values");
        }
```

I would be very happy if anyone could help me fix this annoying bug so that I can continue the development of this application. Thanks in advance!